# How to align a number and line using css?

Tags: html, css, charts

I am making a simple gauge meter which has minimum and maximum value as `0` and `2` respectively.

I am able to achieve the UI so far like,

```css
.sc-gauge  { width:200px; height:200px; margin:200px auto; }

.sc-background { position:relative; height:100px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:gray; border-radius:150px 150px 0 0; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; }

.sc-mask { position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; left:20px; height:80px; background-color:#fff; border-radius:150px 150px 0 0 }

.sc-percentage { position:absolute; top:100px; left:-200%; width:400%; height:400%; margin-left:100px; background-color:#00aeef; }

.sc-percentage { transform:rotate(70deg); transform-origin:top center; }

.sc-min { float:left; }

.sc-max { float:right; }

.sc-avg {position: absolute; top: 75%;left: 50%;}

.sc-value { position:absolute; top:50%; left:0; width:100%;  font-size:48px; font-weight:700 }
```

```html
<div class="sc-gauge">
    <div class="sc-background">
      <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
      <div class="sc-mask"></div>
      <span class="sc-value">0.7 gb</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min">0</span>
    <span class="sc-avg">1</span>
    <span class="sc-max">2</span>
</div>
```

But the expected output needs to be like this,

[image]

The pending UI includes,

-> Placing of `0` and `2` exactly at the left beginning and and right ending of the chart.

-> Making small line in `left`, `top` and `right` of the chart.

-> Placing number `1` at top center of the chart..

If my points are unclear then kindly refer the attached image for exact UI.

Things I have tried to make the number `0` and `2` to left and right like image is,

```
.sc-percentage {
  position: relative;
}

.sc-min {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.sc-max {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

To make the line at top of the chart and to place number `1` there, I have tried,

```
.sc-avg {position: absolute; top: 75%;left: 50%;}
```

But this doesn't work the way as expected ..

I am stuck with this css work for long time.. Please kindly help me to achieve the the exact UI like in the given image.

Comment: this is not responsive. The dimensions are fixed numbers. You might want to try with SVG solution instead: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
(You can adjust the position in the top and left/right css properties)

```css
.sc-gauge  { 
   width:200px; 
   height:200px; 
   margin:200px auto;
 }   
.sc-background { 
   position:relative; 
   height:100px; 
   margin-bottom:10px; 
   background-color:gray; 
   border-radius:150px 150px 0 0; 
   overflow:hidden; 
   text-align:center; 
}

.sc-mask { 
   position:absolute; 
   top:20px; 
   right:20px; 
   left:20px; 
   height:80px; 
   background-color:#fff; 
   border-radius:150px 150px 0 0
}

.sc-percentage { 
   position:absolute;  
   top:100px; 
   left:-200%; 
   width:400%; 
   height:400%; 
   margin-left:100px; 
   background-color:#00aeef; 
}

.sc-percentage { 
   transform:rotate(70deg); 
   transform-origin:top center; 
}

.sc-min { 
  position: relative;
  top:-13%;
  left: -7%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
}
.line-min{
  color: #00aeef;
}
.sc-max { 
  position: relative; 
  top: -13%; 
  left: 82%; 
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
}
.line-max{
  color: gray;
}
.sc-avg {
  position: relative; 
  top: -68%;
  left: 41%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
}
.line-avg {
  position: relative;
  top: -59%;
  right: -37%;
  color: gray;
}
.sc-value { 
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  left:0; 
  width:100%;  
  font-size:38px; 
  font-weight:700; 
}
```

```html
<div class="sc-gauge">
<div class="sc-background">
  <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
  <div class="sc-mask"></div>
  <span class="sc-value">0.7 gb</span>
</div>
<span class="sc-min">0  
  <span class="line-min">_</span>
</span>
<span class="sc-avg">1</span>
<span class="line-avg">|</span>
<span class="sc-max">
  <span class="line-max">_</span> 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the wrap element with class `.sc-gauge` you need add `position: relative;` after this you can use `position: absolute;` for the child elements

Try to replace this classes:

```
.sc-gauge {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}

.sc-min {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}

.sc-avg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -23px;
    left: 50%;
}

.sc-max {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.sc-background {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.sc-mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0
}

.sc-percentage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: -200%;
    width: 400%;
    height: 400%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: #00aeef;
}

.sc-percentage {
    transform: rotate(70deg);
    transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-value {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 700
}

/*  */

.sc-gauge {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}

.sc-min {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}

.sc-avg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -23px;
    left: 50%;
}

.sc-max {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sc-gauge">
    <div class="sc-background">
        <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
        <div class="sc-mask"></div>
        <span class="sc-value">0.7 gb</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min">0</span>
    <span class="sc-avg">1</span>
    <span class="sc-max">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But the number ```1``` is coming to bottom in this case. Also whether using of negative values don't affect the UI in different screens?

Comment: I added an example in my post. Please see the example

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want buddy?

```
.sc-gauge {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 200px auto;
}

.sc-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.sc-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
}

.sc-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(70deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-min {
  float: left;
}

.sc-max {
  float: right;
}

.sc-avg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.sc-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sc-gauge::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/DineshRout/pen/NWdZKMw?editors=1100